# select elements who's attribute match values present in array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Everybody knows that in jQuery, selection by attribute works like this :

```
var abc =$('input[name=iphone]');
```

In my case, I have an array. I want to select elements whose attribute match values in my array.

something like this :

```
var abc =$('input[name in (my_array)]');
```

you see what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to approach it like this:

```
var collection = [];
$("input[name]").each(function () {
    if($.inArray($(this).attr("name"), yourArray)) {
        collection.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: What if the matching elements might include `<select>` or `<option>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can build up a [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) from your array:

```
var arraySelector = $.map(my_array,
    function (item) {
       return "input[name=" + item + "]";
    }).join(",");

var abc = $(arraySelector);
```

Comment: This is a clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is close, but there is one issue: $.inArray returns the index of the value within the array or -1 if it doesn't exist. So I would edit the answer to be:

```
var collection = [];
$("input[name]").each(function () {
    if($.inArray($(this).attr("name"), yourArray) != -1) {
        collection.push($(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_array = [ /* array of names */ ];
var abc = $('input').filter( function(){
    return (my_array.indexOf( this.name ) > -1);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should run a loop on the length of array

```
var abc="";
for(var i=0;i<my_array.length;i++){
abc=$('input[name =+my_array[i]]');
}
```

Comment: This won't get all elements, only the most recently found.

Comment: i have given him the obj he can use it in loop or can put into array according to his requirement